# ACF with Timber&Twig - don't display on front page

Tags: twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I am new to Timber and Twig andnow I encountered problem I cannot solve. I use ACF in page templates and everything works fine but they do not display on front page. {{dump.(post.meta)}} is null

my front-page.php:

```
   <?php


$context          = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
$templates        = array( 'pages/front-page.twig');

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

my front-page.twig:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {{dump(post.meta('header'))}}
    <h1>{{post.meta('header')}}</h1>
    <div class="hero__image__container">
        <img src={{ Image(post.meta('img')).src }}/>
    </div>
    {% include 'parts/banner.twig' %}
    {% include 'parts/services.twig' with {'items': services.get_items} %}#}

{% endblock %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get a single post in Timber, you would use `Timber::get_post()`.

```php
<?php

$context         = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = Timber::get_post();
$templates       = array( 'pages/front-page.twig' );

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

When you use `Timber\PostQuery`, you get a collection of posts in return, which behaves like an array. Before you could use `{{ post.meta() }}`, you’d first have to access the first post in that array.